# Partial Update using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, http-patch

I am working on a Java Spring Boot project. I have an entity that has 20 fields. I currently have an put method that takes these 20 fields, all of them are non-nulls and I validate them using validators including my custom validators. But it is costly. Even if I want to change a single field in my db, I completely fetch the row, update all fields using custom mapper and save into db. In this implementation, even if only one field changes, I have to send all fields in request and also I overwrite 19 unchanged field into db which is costly. I am looking for solutions to:

1. I should be able to send only fields that is supposed to change and I should be able to validate them in DTO level using validator (for example: I should be able to check if a values between 0 and 100. In current implementation I have a custom validator for this)
2. I should be able to overwrite only changed fields into db. I shouldnt overwrite values that should remain same.
3. (kind of optional) It would be better if it can be generic. I can easily adapt for my different controllers.

I have been searching Java Reflections and found this implementation:

```
    @PatchMapping("/{id}")
    public Product updateProductFields(@PathVariable int id,@RequestBody Map<String, Object> fields){
        return service.updateProductByFields(id,fields);
    }
```

```
    public Product updateProductByFields(int id, Map<String, Object> fields) {
        Optional<Product> existingProduct = repository.findById(id);

        if (existingProduct.isPresent()) {
            fields.forEach((key, value) -> {
                Field field = ReflectionUtils.findField(Product.class, key);
                field.setAccessible(true);
                ReflectionUtils.setField(field, existingProduct.get(), value);
            });
            return repository.save(existingProduct.get());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

```
public interface ProductRepository extends
        JpaRepository<Product, Integer> {


}
```

But I am not sure if this satisfies my desires. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Personally I wouldn't use `Map<String, Object>` to represent the patch. I'd just use an instance of `Product` with null fields. This way it's typesafe and you benefit from code completion etc.

Comment: In current implementation I have a request DTO which is used in both creation and updating. It has custom validation annotations for checking if a value is null (and more). I cannot use this dto if I want to send null values so I have to duplicate a DTO in this case for allowing patch fields to be nullable, but I have to duplicate for all my update DTOs in this case. Moreover, implementing different DTO's with validations seems to be overkill because my entity contains 40+ fields. I cannot create a seprate DTO for each update case. What would you suggest in this case?

Comment: Perhaps `Map<String, Object>` is ok.  Another option is to generate some logic using an [annotation processor](https://www.baeldung.com/java-annotation-processing-builder). Or perhaps you might want to generate some java code at build time based on your existing model (eg invoking [qdox](https://github.com/paul-hammant/qdox) and [freemarker](https://freemarker.apache.org/index.html) via maven)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefer type safety so don't like dealing with `Map<String, Object>`.

You mentioned in a comment that you want to do this for many different DTO's, each with many fields. I think you should consider generating code using an [annotation processor](https://www.baeldung.com/java-annotation-processing-builder). This would allow you to generate an `XDelta` and an `XMerger` for each of your model classes.

eg You could annotate the `Product` class with a custom `@Delta` annotation

```java
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface Delta {
}

@Delta
public class Product {
   @Id
   private Long id;
   
   @NotEmpty 
   private String name;
   
   @GreaterThan(0) 
   private BigDecimal price;
}
```

The annotation processor would then generate

```java
@Generated("generated by DeltaAnnotationProcessor")
public class ProductDelta {
   public Long getId() { ... }

   public void setName(String name) { ... }
   public boolean isNameSet() { ... }
   public String getName() { ... }

   public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) { ... }
   public boolean isPriceSet() { ... }
   public BigDecimal getPrice() { ... }
}

@Generated("generated by DeltaAnnotationProcessor")
public class ProductMerger {
   public Product merge(Product product, ProductDelta delta) { 
      String name = delta.isNameSet() ? delta.getName() : product.getName();
      BigDecimal price = delta.isPriceSet() ? delta.getPrice() : product.getPrice();
      return new Product(product.getId(), name, price, ...);
   }
}
```

For generating code I usually use [freemarker](https://freemarker.apache.org/index.html)

Comment: What library does the `@Merger` annotation belong to?

Comment: This annotation would need to be created by the OP

Comment: I cannot understand what this code does. Could you explain it more?

Comment: With an annotation processor you can generate whatever code you like. In my example the `ProductDelta` would contain the changes to a product (eg instead of `Map<String, Object>`). And the `ProductMerger` is able to join/merge a `Product` with a `ProductDelta` to obtain a new `Product` instance with both the old and new values. But you could generate whatever code you require via an [annotation processor](https://www.baeldung.com/java-annotation-processing-builder)